# Error DOMDocument::loadXML() when loading xml file on server

Tags: php, xml

I have a problem with loading xml file on http server (on localhost -windows - everything works fine). When I trying run script to update instock products (prestashop store) from xml file I getting this error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag
>   expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in
>   /home/fi164048/public_html/import/magazyn2.php on line 35

To download and load xml file I using this function:

```
$xmlfile = 'import/'.time().'.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents("http://urladreeess.pl/ShowXml.ashx?id=3");
$download = file_put_contents($xmlfile, $xml); 
if($download){
    echo "Success!<br>";
} else { echo "Fail!<br>"; }

$oDOM = new DOMDocument();
$oDOM->loadXML($xmlfile);
```

File is correctly creating in import directory. When I tried to change `loadXML` to `load` function I'm getting `500 Internal Server Error`.

Any sugestion how can I load this xml file? I will be grateful for any suggestion.

Ps. sorry for my bad english

XML FILE STRUCTURE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE nokaut SYSTEM "http://www.nokaut.pl/integracja/nokaut.dtd"><nokaut generator="Comarch ERP e-Sklep" ver="7.2"><offers><offer><id>5</id><name>ANTENKI DO SIATKÓWKI /2szt/</name><description>Antenka do siatkówki. </description><price>21.22</price><weight>1.000</weight><category>Sport i hobby / Sporty drużynowe / Siatkówka</category><instock>51</instock></offer>
```

Comment: What is the real URL you are using for `file_get_contents()`? Or what does the data look like?

Comment: XML FILE STRUCTURE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE nokaut SYSTEM "http://www.nokaut.pl/integracja/nokaut.dtd"><nokaut generator="Comarch ERP e-Sklep" ver="7.2"><offers><offer><id>5</id><name>ANTENKI DO SIATKÓWKI /2szt/</name><description>Antenka do siatkówki. </description><price>21.22</price><weight>1.000</weight><category>Sport i hobby / Sporty drużynowe / Siatkówka</category><instock>51</instock></offer>

Comment: [`DOMDocument::loadXML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) loads from a string not a file(name).

Comment: loadXML on my localhost works fine and loading file as string
but on server it dosent work :/
when i change it to 
$oDOM = new DOMDocument();
$oDOM->load($xmlfile);
im getting 500 Internal server error